# Ordered triples that sastify the system.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find all the real system solutions:

$$2x+x^2y=y$$
$$2y+y^2z=z$$
$$2z+z^2x=x$$

My attempt

Trivial solution : (0,0,0)

We have:

$$\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1-x^2}{2x}$$

$$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1-y^2}{2y}$$

$$\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1-z^2}{2z}$$

Then:

$$x+\frac{1}{x} + y+\frac{1}{y} + z+\frac{1}{z}=0$$

How to procede?

Comment: The general solution is by using Groebner bases. But you tagged it as pre-calculus.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Yes, exactly. But taking resultants is enough, this is much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y=\dfrac{2x}{1-x^2}$$  immediately commands me to use $x=\tan A$

to find $$y=\tan2A,z=\tan(2\cdot2A),x=\tan(2\cdot4A)$$

$$\implies\tan8A=\tan A$$

$\implies8A=n\pi+A$ where $n$ is any integer

Answer (score 0):

Using resultants we can write down all solutions over $\Bbb C$, and then look for the real solutions. They are
$$
(x,y,z)=(0,0,0),(i,i,i),(-i,-i,-i)
$$
and
$$
y=\frac{x(x^4 - 20x^2 + 15)}{4},\quad 
z=\frac{x( - 3x^4 + 62x^2 - 87)}{8},
$$
where $x$ is a root of the polynomial
$$
x^6 - 21x^4 + 35x^2 - 7=0.
$$
This polynomial has six real roots! It is cubic in $y=x^2$.